# Hot rodding the fender 100 rumble

Tags: instruments, equipment

I am looking for information on replacing 12 bass driver with a very good quality driver and possibly
Stiffening cabinet using acoustic foam.
I plan on using other amplification.
And or using fenders built in unit.

Comment: It’s not clear what your question is